# Find volume by using triple integration

Tags: definite-integrals

I have trouble setting up a triple integral to find volume bound by equations, such as:

I'm not sure how to figure how to find the boundaries for the $z$-axis. How would I go about setting up the triple integral ?
Find the volume bounded by $z^2 =  x^2 + y^2$ and  $z = \sqrt{9-x^2 - y^2}$

Comment: The general procedure: First figure out what types of surfaces those two equations represent.  Then [draw a picture](http://i.imgur.com/3Rubv2c.png).  Then, based on any symmetries present, decide which coordinate system would work best.  Finally, try to find inequalities which describe the region.

Comment: Also note, you don't necessarily have to bound the entire region with one set of inequalities.  You are allowed to break up the region into parts if that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is a solid of revolution (around the z-axis), then use 
the second Pappus's centroid theorem. 
I add some details :

1. $z^2=x^2+y^2$ is a cone (just think that with $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ it has equation $z=\pm r$. This cone is generated by the lines $z=x,y=0$ and $z=-x,y=0$ (just draw them :) rotating around the $z$-axis

   $z = \sqrt{9-x^2 - y^2}=\sqrt{9-(x^2 + y^2)}=\sqrt{9-r^2}$ is generated by the curve $z=\sqrt{9-x^2},y=0$ rotating around the $z$-axis. This is a semi-circle.

Hope it helps. Do not hesitate to interact.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}}\int_{0}^{r} r dz drd\theta + \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}}^{3}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-r^2}} r dz drd\theta
$$